# Python how to add the values in an object with the corresponding index value in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

im trying to create a ranking system to order the fruits in the order of biggest to smallest:

```
is_big = [None,None,10,1/100,-1/100]
```

i need to add the values of is_big[i] corresponding with the indexes of fruits object

```
fruits = [['Pear','green',2,3,5],
          ['Apple','red',5,2,10],
          ['mango','yellow',4,6,12]]
```

to make the ranking system im giving a score based on the fruits element values and the values of is_big i need to multiply is_big[i] with fruits[i] and sum it up ,where is_big != None 
the expected results should be fruits_ranking =[[19.98],[49.92],[39.94]]
so that after sorting fruits_ranking i get the results

```
fruits =[['Apple','red',5,2,10],
          ['mango','yellow',4,6,12],
          ['Pear','green',2,3,5]]
```

my code so far is:

```
rs = []
for i in range(len(fruits)):
      for c in range(len(is_big)):
              if battery[c]!= None and not isinstance(is_big[i],str):
                      rs.append(is_big[i]*fruits[c])
```

as you can see my code does not work any kind of help would be appreciated

Comment: what is `phones`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) with a specific function `score` as `key` parameter that computes the score you need. The score you describe is the sum of a [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) with `is_big`, that's why converting to `np.ndarray` proves useful as it enables you to do dot products as easily as with a `*`!

```
import numpy as np

# avoid Nones, convert to np.ndarray to enable dot product
coeffs = np.array(is_big[2:])  

def score(input_fruit):
    input_numeric = np.array(input_fruit[2:])  # keep only numerical values
    return (input_numeric * coeffs).sum()  # dot product & sum
```

First, you can check that scores match your requirements:

```
>>> print(list(zip(fruits, map(score, fruits))))

[
    (["Pear", "green", 2, 3, 5], 19.98),
    (["Apple", "red", 5, 2, 10], 49.92),
    (["mango", "yellow", 4, 6, 12], 39.940000000000005),
]
```

Now sort:

```
# reverse=True for descending order
>>> print(sorted(fruits, key=score, reverse=True))  

[["Apple", "red", 5, 2, 10], ["mango", "yellow", 4, 6, 12], ["Pear", "green", 2, 3, 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is using below

```
[[i,sum(x*y for x,y in zip(i[2:],[0 if v is None else v for v in is_big][2:]))] for i in prod]
```

Output:

```
[[['Pear', 'green', 2, 3, 5], 19.98],
 [['Apple', 'red', 5, 2, 10], 49.92],
 [['mango', 'yellow', 4, 6, 12], 39.940000000000005]]
```

Answer (score 0):

An `itertools` solution might be:

```
import itertools as it
import operator as op

is_big = [None, None, 10, 1/100, -1/100]
fruits = [["Pear", "green", 2, 3, 5], ["Apple", "red", 5, 2, 10], ["mango", "yellow", 4, 6, 12]]

fr_ranks = [sum(fr*val for fr, val in zip_one if val is not None)
            for zip_one in it.starmap(zip, zip(fruits, it.repeat(is_big)))]
# [19.98, 49.92, 39.940000000000005]

sorted_fruits, _ = zip(*sorted(zip(fruits, fr_ranks), key=op.itemgetter(1), reverse=True))
# (['Apple', 'red', 5, 2, 10], ['mango', 'yellow', 4, 6, 12], ['Pear', 'green', 2, 3, 5])
```

First, we align each fruit list in `fruits` with the value list `is_big` via *repeating* `is_big` and `zip`ping it with the fruits, which will give 2-tuples of such list pairs when evaluated. Then `it.starmap`, with its function argument being `zip`, generates the desired fruit-value pairs that will reside in `zip_one`. A sum of products while skipping `None`'s will give the fruit rankings.

Then we sort the `fruits` and this is sorting two parallel lists where the key is the corresponding element of `fr_ranks`. This gives a `tuple` but you can easily cast to `list`.